# Biharmonic Equation in a Rectangle with Some Uncommon Boundary Conditions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, linear-pde

I asked this question on [Mathematics network](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1621594/biharmonic-equation-in-a-rectangle-with-some-uncommon-boundary-conditions) but it didn't receive any answers. So I assume it is just beyond the classic things in PDEs and I decided to ask it here too.

Consider the following boundary value problem (BVP)

$$\matrix{
   {{\Delta ^2}H = 0,} \hfill & {} \hfill & {{\rm{in}}\,} \hfill & \Omega  \hfill  \cr 
   {\partial _y^2H = 0} \hfill & {{\partial _x}{\partial _y}H = 0} \hfill & {{\rm{on}}} \hfill & {{S_1}} \hfill  \cr 
   {\partial _y^2H = 0} \hfill & {{\partial _x}{\partial _y}H = 0} \hfill & {{\rm{on}}} \hfill & {{S_2}} \hfill  \cr 
   {\partial _x^2H = 0} \hfill & {{\partial _x}{\partial _y}H = 0} \hfill & {{\rm{on}}} \hfill & {{S_3}} \hfill  \cr 
   {\partial _x^2H = 0} \hfill & {{\partial _x}{\partial _y}H = 0} \hfill & {{\rm{on}}} \hfill & {{S_4}} \hfill  \cr 
 } \tag{1}$$

where

$$\eqalign{
   & \Delta^2 = \partial_{x}^{4}+2\partial_{x}^{2}\partial_{y}^{2}+\partial_{y}^{4}
\cr
  & \Omega  = \left\{ {\left( {x,y} \right): - a < x < a, - b < y < b} \right\}  \cr 
  & {S_1} = \left\{ {\left( {x,y} \right):x = a, - b \le y \le b} \right\}  \cr 
  & {S_2} = \left\{ {\left( {x,y} \right):x =  - a, - b \le y \le b} \right\}  \cr 
  & {S_3} = \left\{ {\left( {x,y} \right): - a \le x \le a,y = b} \right\}  \cr 
  & {S_4} = \left\{ {\left( {x,y} \right): - a \le x \le a,y =  - b} \right\}  \cr 
  & \partial \Omega  = \bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^4 {{S_i}}  \cr} \tag{2}$$

The function $H:\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ is considered to belong to $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

Then I want to show that

$$\begin{align}
\partial_{x}^{2}H&=0 \qquad \text{in} \qquad \Omega\\
\partial_{y}^{2}H&=0 \qquad \text{in} \qquad \Omega\\
{\partial _x}{\partial _y}H&=0 \qquad \text{in} \qquad \Omega
\end{align} 
\tag{3}$$

But I don't have any idea on how to proceed!

Any hints or help is appreciated. :)